# Banach space of discontinuous functions on a product space

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, banach-spaces

**Edit:** According to comments of Eric Wofsy  and  Yemon Choi I edit the question.

For  a (compact) topological  space $X$, we put $A=\{f:X\to \mathbb{C}\mid f\text{ is  bounded}\}$. We define a  semi-norm on $A$  with $\parallel f \parallel=\parallel \omega_{f}\parallel_{\infty}$  where $\omega_{f}(x)$  is  the  oscilation  of  $f$  at  $x$. It defines a  norm on $A/C(X)$. The  completion of this  normed space is  denoted  by $DC(X)$.

> How can $DC(X\times Y)$ be written in term of $DC(X)$ and $DC(Y)$?(An appropriate completion of the algebraic tensor product $DC(X)\otimes DC(Y)$? (Or some thing  else?)

**Note:** We can not expect to have an  algebra  structure on $DC(X)$, since $C(X)$ is  not an ideal. But in the following  particular case we may expect that we have a Banach algebra structure:  When $X$ is  a  compact  topological group with its Haar measure, $A$ is the algebra of  bounded measurable  functions with the convolution product. again we consider the oscillation norm.  For abelian $X$, it would be interesting to  study the Gelfand spectrum of the resulting commutative Banach algebra. In particular, what is the resulting algebra and its Gelfand spectrum in the particular case of $X=S^{1}$?

Comment: Why would you expect this to be true?  Oscillation is not multiplicative, and there is no obvious map $A(X)/C(X)\otimes A(Y)/C(Y)\to A(X\times Y)/C(X\times Y)$.

Comment: You do realize that the projective t.p. of C(X) with C(Y) is usually not isomorphic to $C(X\times Y)$? As @EricWofsey says, why would you expect this result to be true?

Comment: @EricWofsey    Thanks  for  your  two  comments. so may be I  should  change the  first part to the following: How$ DC(X\times Y)$  can be written in term of DC(X)  and  DC(Y)