# The category of discontinuous Banach spaces

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ct.category-theory, gn.general-topology, banach-spaces

A banach  space is  discontinuous if it is  isometric  to  $DC(X)$  for  some   Hausdorff  topological space $X$. ($DC(X)$ is  defined [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/191631/banach-space-of-discontinuous-functions-on-a-product-space). We denote  by $DBan$, the  category of  all discontinuous  Banach  spaces with norm decreasing linear morphisms.  The  category of  Hausdorff  topological  spaces is  denoted  by $HTop$(The  morphisms   are  continuous  maps).  Then  we have  a  contravariant  functor  $X\to DC(X)$ from $HTop$  to  $DBan$. Now we  have  two  questions:

> 1. To  what  extent $DBan$  is  known?In particular: is it true that every infinite  dimensional  Banach  space belongs to $DBan$?
> 2. Is $DC(X)$ a full functor?